# NSString init with data by encoding NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding fails on IOS 8 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstringencoding

I used to be able to convert EUC japanese data into NSString by using the following code.  The expected result is "目標".
But I just tried to use IOS 8 simulator and the result is null.

```
const char bytes[]={0xcc, 0xdc, 0xc9, 0xb8};


NSData *d=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSString *s=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

Any one knows if this is a bug or something I failed to notice?

Comment: Assuming `bytes` really is a valid Japanese EUC string, then that looks perfectly valid to me and must be a bug in `NSString`. I would double and triple check the data is correct, and then file a TSI with Apple asking for help. https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Filed a bug 18865187 with outputs on different versions.  Let's see how it goes.